# Using Nginx to host several web apps under one domain

Tags: nginx, web-applications, webserver

I would like to host a few web apps on a web server I'm setting up with Nginx (via Nginx Proxy Manager). At this time, I have one domain and no subdomains. Instead, I'd like to host the web apps as subpages; for example:

- `www.example.com/` would point to, for example, the Homarr web app. I can get this working no problem.
- `www.example.com/nginx` would take me to the Nginx Proxy Manager configuration page.
- `www.example.com/homepage` would take me to the Homepage web app.

I can get the root address ([www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/)) working properly with any web app I choose. However, I cannot get any of the subpages to work as intended. I get either 404 errors or blank pages.

I suspect this is because each web app expects to be at the root. Each app has its own set of subpages (for example, Nginx Proxy Manager has `/login`, `/nginx/proxy`, `/nginx/access`, and so on), so putting each web app at any location other than the root messes things up without further configuration.

I am new to Nginx syntax, so I really don't know a whole lot. I've searched for quite a while for a solution, but I haven't found one yet. Two of the most recent configurations I've tried are shown below, though I've tried countless variations.

First:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass $forward_scheme://$server:$port;
}

location ^~ /homepage/ {
    proxy_pass $forward_scheme://homepage:3000;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;

    proxy_buffering off;
}

location ^~ /nginx/ {
    proxy_pass $forward_scheme://npm-app-1:81;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;

    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

Second:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass $forward_scheme://$server:$port/;
}

location ^~ ^/nginx/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass $forward_scheme://npm-app-1:81/$1/;
}

location ^~ ^/homepage/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass $forward_scheme://homepage:3000/$1/;
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the `access.log` and `error.log`?